# Unable to find an inherited method for function ‘writeRaster’ for signature ‘"SpatialGridDataFrame", "character"’

Tags: raster, r, geotiff-tiff, export, rgdal

I have the following error when trying to use the `writeraster` function in R:

> Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
>     unable to find an inherited method for function ‘writeRaster’ for signature ‘"SpatialGridDataFrame", "character"’

This is the code:

```
library(rgdal)
x <- readGDAL("LC81360442014322LGN00_B5.TIF")
z <- reflconv(x,2.0000E-05,-0.100000)
writeRaster(z,filename="test.tif",format="GTiff",overwrite=TRUE) #ERROR LINE
```

I want to store variable z in a raster file. Can any one help me out from this error?

Comment: It is unclear where you get this error. Please edit your question to make it clearer.

Comment: when I try to convert the landsat band5 image to reflectance i got this error

Comment: Do you have to use `readGDAL?` You could try `raster("LC81360442014322LGN00_B5.TIF")`?

Comment: And you also need to load library(landsat8)

Comment: landsat8 is also there

Comment: if i try with raster(.tif) i am facing this error

Comment: Error in as.vector(data) : 
  no method for coercing this S4 class to a vector

Comment: The raster::writeRaster function is expecting a raster class object so, just coerce to a raster, even on-the-fly writeRaster(raster(z,1),filename="test.tif")

Answer (score 5):

First coerce z to a RasterLayer:

```
z <- raster(z)
writeRaster(z, filename="test.tif", overwrite=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you import your file with `gdal`, it is best to export it with `gdal`, too:

```
x<-readGDAL("LE71930232012260EDC00_B5.TIF")
# str(x) #what is the Formal class of your raster
# > Formal class 'SpatialGridDataFrame'
z<-reflconv(x,2.0000E-05,-0.100000)
writeGDAL(z, fname="test_gdal.tif", drivername = "GTiff")
```